# Java- Basic IO trouble

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to code a sieve of eratosthenes which I intend to use to find the largest prime factor of 13195. If this works, I intend to use it on the number: 600851475143.

Since creating a list of numbers ranging from 2-600851475143 would be nearly impossible due to memory issues, I have decided to store the numbers in a text file instead.

The problem I'm running into though is that instead of getting a text file filled with numbers, the code only produces a file with one number (this is my first time work with IO related stuff in Java):

```
        long number = 13195;
        long limit = (long) Math.sqrt(number);



        for (long i = 2; i < limit + 1; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Writer output = null;
                File file = new File("Primes.txt");
                output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

                output.write(Long.toString(i) + "\n");
                output.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Here's the output contained the text file:
114

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Erathostenes - it's too slow unless you need all the primes in the range.

Here is a better way to factorize a given number. The function returns a map, where the keys are the prime factors of n and the values are their powers. E.g. for 13195 it will be {5:1, 7:1, 13:1, 29:1}

It's complexity is O(sqrt(n)):

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> Factorize(int n){
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> ret = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    int origN = n;
    for(int p = 2; p*p <= origN && n > 1; p += (p == 2 ? 1: 2)){
        int power = 0;
        while (n % p == 0){
            ++power;
            n /= p;
        }
        if(power > 0)
            ret.put(p, power);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Of course if you need just the largest prime factor you can return the last p only not the whole map - the complexity is the same.

Comment: Fiver, I was going through your code and while I mostly get it, I was a little confused as to why you are keeping a track of "power" when it seems like all you really need is just "p"? And also, why did you use a HashMap? Thanks.

Comment: As I said in the last sentence - this function fully factorizes the number - it does more than what you need, but with no extra complexity. So yeah you can just return the last p and you don't need a hash map. I just like to buy one get one free :)

Comment: Thanks for responding. Anyways I had another question: Why did you write this " p*p <= origN" when you could have written "p <= math.sqrt(origN)"? Is it just personal preference or is there more behind it? :)

Comment: well, multiplication is faster than taking square root, but other than that it's exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

Your code keep re-opening, writing, and closing the same file.  You should do something like this:

```
long number = 13195;
long limit = (long) Math.sqrt(number);

try
{
    File file = new File("Primes.txt");
    Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

    for (long i = 2; i < limit + 1; i++)
    {
        output.write(Long.toString(i) + "\n");
    }

    output.close();
}
catch (IOException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are recreating your filewriter in every iteration of your for-loop and not specifying it to append so you are overwriting your file in every iteration.

Try changing it to create your filewriter before your for-loop and close it after the loop.  Something like this:

```
long number = 13195;
long limit = (long) Math.sqrt(number);

Writer output = null;
try
{
    File file = new File("/var/tmp/Primes.txt");
    output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    for (long i = 2; i < limit + 1; i++) {
        output.write(Long.toString(i) + "\n");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    output.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the file instantiation out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your file on every pass through the loop.
You need to open your file outside the main loop.

```
    long number = 13195;
    long limit = (long) Math.sqrt(number);


    try
    {
        Writer output = null;
        File file = new File("Primes.txt");
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // Cannot open file
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (long i = 2; i < limit + 1; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            output.write(Long.toString(i) + "\n");
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    output.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Saving directly to disk is slower, have you considered doing this in pieces, then saving to disk? It could also have the benefit of smaller file size, since you can write only the primes you have found, instead of every composite number.